# Convenience inits in class hierarchy cause infinite recursion

Tags: swift, initialization, swift2, designated-initializer

I have a hierarchy of 2 classes in Swift 2.0. Both classes can be instantiated by passing the arguments or by passing a JSON dictionary (`[String: AnyObject]`) which contains the arguments.

The inits that directly take the arguments are `designated inits`, while those that take the JSON are `convenience inits` with **the same signature**.

```
class Thing {
    let name : String

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init(jsonNamed: String){

        // read the json, parse and extract
        // the name
        self.init(name: "got this from JSON")
    }
}

class SubThing : Thing{

    var surname : String

    init(name: String, surname: String){
        self.surname = surname
        super.init(name: name)
    }


    convenience init(jsonNamed: String){

        self.init(jsonNamed: "got this from JSON")
        // extract surname
        self.surname = "Got this from json"


    }

}
```

The `convenience` init in `SubThing` is not allowed to call the same init in super, and if I call it in self, it will cause an infinite recursion, as both methods `have the same signature`.

If I make both json inits `designated` ones, I can't call `self.init(name:)` in `Thing`, and I would have to repeat the same code in both initialisers in `Thing`.

What's the best way to get around this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a loop in `SubThing` calling the same designated initializer from itself. I see it rewritten this way:

```
class Thing {
    private var name : String?

    private init() {}

    convenience init(name: String){
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init(jsonNamed: String){
        self.init()
        self.name = getNameFromJSON()
    }

    private func getNameFromJSON() -> String {
        // read the json, parse and extract
        // the name
        return "got this from JSON"
    }
}

class SubThing : Thing {
    private var surname : String?

    convenience init(name: String, surname: String){
        self.init(name: name)
        self.surname = surname
    }


    convenience init(jsonNamed: String){
        self.init()
        self.name = getNameFromJSON()
        // extract surname
        self.surname = "Got this from json"
    }
}
```

Tested and working. **UPDATE**: added private inits, so it couldn't be initialized empty.

Comment: I decided to move all the json parsing out of the inits and into a function that returns a struct with all the correct and typed info, similar to what [Aeson](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json) does for Haskell. You answer set me in the right direction, thanks! :-)